# GetRuntimeProperties instead of GetProperty

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to find property inside of generic type. This is an old way (and since my code is dedicated for WinRT I believe I need another approach):

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(TRp).GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperty(idField, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

I need to achieve the same result using `GetRuntimeProperties`. This is my approach:

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(TRp).GenericTypeArguments[0].GetRuntimeProperties().Single(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == idField.ToUpper()...
```

as you can see I implemented `IgnoreCase` in a custom way, probably it can be done better?
How can I implement remaining `BindingFlags`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually dont need to. This is how [`Type.GetRuntimeProperties`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/RuntimeReflectionExtensions.cs,f492df3d5b67c9ae) is implemented:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetRuntimeProperties(this Type type)
{
    CheckAndThrow(type);

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = type.GetProperties(everything);
    return properties;
}
```

Where `everything` is defined as following:

```
private const BindingFlags everything = BindingFlags.Instance |
                                        BindingFlags.Public | 
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                        BindingFlags.Static;
```

Which means it will already look for your required flags.

**Edit:**

If you want to specify `BindingFlags` yourself, you can write your own custom extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(this TypeInfo type, 
                                                             BindingFlags bindingFlags)
    {
        var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(bindingFlags);

        var subtype = type.BaseType;
        if (subtype != null)
            list.AddRange(subtype.GetTypeInfo().GetAllProperties(bindingFlags));

        return propertyInfos.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note this **hasn't been tested**. It is merely an attempt to show you that you can do it yourself.

Comment: 1. How did you figure out how it is implemented?

Comment: 2. What if I want to change some of the `BindingFlags`?

Comment: 1. I added a link to my post (click on `Type.GetRuntimeTypes`). 2. Unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: There must be some way of getting rid of for example `BindingFlags.NonPublic` from results. Maybe we can retract it from results?

Comment: @JacekWojcik See my edit. I've added an *attempt* to retrieve types yourself.

Comment: Looks to me that I cannot use `BindingFlags` type in my project :-(

Comment: What is your project type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68659/discussion-between-jacek-wojcik-and-yuval-itzchakov).